# Trying to find isogram in a string c++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

I am trying to write a code that has two functions: one that determines whether the string is an **isogram** or not and another one to print the outcome (true or false) to the console (for the purpose of solving the task).

Some of the things are not working correctly though. And I wonder where I need to improve the code (probably all over...). I would appreciate any advice :)

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<iomanip>


bool find_Isogram (std::string str)
{
std::sort(str.begin(), str.end()); //sorted the string for the for loop (e.g. eHllo)

 int length = str.length();

 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
    if (str.at(i) == str.at(i+1))
        {
            return false;
            break;
        }
    else
    {
        return true;

    }
}
}

void print_result()
{
     std::string str;
     if (!find_Isogram (str))
     {
      std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
     }

else
{
   std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
}

}

int main()
{

find_Isogram ("gdtub");
print_result();


return 0;

};
````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Also, you do not need a `break` after `return`

Comment: Adding to @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ's post, what do you think will your program do for the input `ABA`?

Comment: An isogram is a word that contains no repeating letters, e.g. 'isogram' :)

Comment: Please tell us what _"things are not working correctly"_ and how do you notice they are not wroking. For example show us input, expected and actual output.

Comment: For instance, if I input "tree" I would expect it to return false because "tree" is not an isogram. That is basically all I need to know. I used the header file because I tried different approaches that I found while checking for ideas in forums. And no, I do not really understand that header file to be honest ;) still learning...

Comment: That's fine. Everyone has to start somewhere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems here:

## 1) You always check an empty string:

`print_result` will just check an empty string, but it's redundant anyway.

```
void print_result()
{
     std::string str;         // empty string
     if (!find_Isogram (str)) // finding isogram on empty string
     {
         std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
     }
     ...
}
```

It can be simplified with [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) that allows you to print a `bool` as `"true"` or `"false"` (instead of 1 or 0). `main` would become

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << find_Isogram ("gdtub"); // prints true or false
};
```

## 2) Isogram check always ends after first character

Take a look at the condition in `find_Isogram`. It has a `return`-statement in the `if` *and* `else`, so you always return after checking the first character.
The idea to detect duplicate characters this way is correct (except for the off-by-one-error already mentioned by others). But you want to `return true;` only after checking *all* of the characters, e.g. outside the loop:

```
bool find_Isogram (std::string str)
{
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end()); //sorted the string for the for loop (e.g. eHllo)

    int length = str.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (str.at(i) == str.at(i+1))
        {
            return false; // whoops duplicate char, stop here
        }
    }    
  
    return true; // no duplicates found, it's an isogram
}
```

---

For some further C++-magic, you could simplify it even more with standard library functions :D

```
bool find_Isogram (std::string str)
{
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    return std::unique(str.begin(), str.end()) == str.end();
}
```

Comment: Thank all of you! Finally after hours of 'playing around' with that piece of code it works and I can sleep better :)

Comment: Using the end function to check. Great Idea. Umm, does unique return the same container (unlike erase which copies the elements to be kept in a different container and returns that container)?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 `std::unique` works only on sorted containers by moving elements in such a way that unique elements are at the beginning. Then it returns an iterator to the first not unique element (the reference is more detailed there). If this iterator is the end-iterator it means there were only unique elements :)

Answer (score 1):

The condition where you check the consecutive characters for equality is wrong. It will yield true for strings like `ABAB`. You instead need to use a map with count of each character that has appeared.

Something like:

```
std::map<char, int> map_of_chars;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    map_of_chars[str.at(i)] = map_of_chars[str.at(i)] + 1;
}
```

If any value in the map is more than `1` return false;

Another implementation would be using the return value of `std::unique()`:

```
std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
auto intial_size = str.size();
std::unique(str.begin(), str.end());
if(str.size() == initial_size) {
    /is an isogram
}
else {
    //is not an isogram
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. The thing that is bothering me is that this challenge seems to be 'easy' but implementing the different functions for this code (unique, map of...) for me is not 'easy' :)

Comment: Hmm... I suggest you go with the `unique` implementation. That's as easy as it can get :)